# haxm installed successfully but still can't run app

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, haxm

Intel HAXM installs successfully (according to the log) both through Android Studio and directly from Intel's executable. However, Android Studio says "HAXM is not installed" and prompts me to install it in an endless cycle (Not installed, install? Installed successfully. Not installed, install?). I am new to all this so could someone help me out with simple words, thanks!

Comment: Try Restarting after installing

Comment: I tried it still didnt wokr